# Copy from HDD to table

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to copy files from C: drive to a table in postgresql but there is a syntax error that I cannot resolve.

```
COPY address_alias_type_aut
C:\GNAF\Authority Code\Authority_Code_ADDRESS_ALIAS_TYPE_AUT_psv.csv' DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER;
```

But it will not run:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "C"
LINE 3: C:\GNAF\Authority Code\Authority_Code_ADDRESS_ALIAS_TYPE_AUT...
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 30
```

I've searched this forum and found reference to escape backslashes and slashes but neither works as per:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "C"
LINE 1: COPY address_alias_type_aut from C:\\GNAF\\Authority Code\\A...
                                         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 34
```

and

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "C"
LINE 1: COPY address_alias_type_aut from C://GNAF//Authority Code//A...
                                         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 34
```

```
COPY address_alias_type_aut from C:\\GNAF\\Authority Code\\Authority_Code_ADDRESS_ALIAS_TYPE_AUT_psv.csv' DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER;
COPY address_type_aut from C:\\GNAF\\Authority Code\\Authority_Code_ADDRESS_TYPE_AUT_psv.csv' DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER;
```

Results for each version - single forward or backslash, and double forward or backslash is the same - error at C

Comment: `COPY address_alias_type_aut C:\GNAF\Authority Code\Authority_Code_ADDRESS_ALIAS_TYPE_AUT_psv.csv' DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER;` There is a ' missing at the beginning of the path

Comment: version PostgreSQL-10.4